# Format string exploitation

Tags: c, exploit

I've been following along with a book titled *Hacking : The Art of Exploitation*, however I have hit a rut when tasked with understanding the format string exploit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int test = 43;
    //int *whereat = &test;
    char buffer[100];

    memset(buffer, '\0', 100);
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    buffer[strlen(argv[1])] = '\n';
    printf(buffer);

    if(test == 62){
        printf("\nHacked\n");
    }else{
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d", test);
        printf("\n");   
    }

}
```

The above code is a test dummy I've set up where you have to overwrite test with 62 in order to display a hacked message. In order to do this I have used gdb to determine the address of test to be 0x7fffffffdec4. I am most familiar with four byte addresses so I was unsure what to do when the address became longer. That said, I tried to write the longer address into the first 6 bytes of the input string as "\xc4\xde\xff\xff\xff\x7f" along with 7 "%08x" (to reach the string on the stack) and a %n to at least overwrite the test variable, however my attempts have yet to succeed. :( Im running ubuntu, ASLR is turned off and so are stack canaries, so the segfault that I keep getting must a result of improper addressing. Any help is greatly appreciated and let me know if any other information can help.

The address I use for test is from gdb:

```
(gdb) list 1
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
5       
6       int test = 43;
7       //int *whereat = &test;
8       char buffer[100];
9       memset(buffer, '\0', 100);
10      strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40065c: file fmt_exploit.c, line 7.
(gdb) run aa
Starting program: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/dir/fmt_exploit aa

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdfb8) at fmt_exploit.c:13
13      printf(buffer);
(gdb) print &test
$1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdec4
```

As you can see from the last line the address of test is 0x7fffffffdec4. How should I write this address into my string to make a "%n" overwrite possible?

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with raw addresses at all. The contents of `argv[1]` are only being looked at by the `strcpy` and `strlen` functions, right? So either the `strcpy` is going to do a buffer overflow, or `buffer[strlen(argv[1])]`. In the case of `buffer[strlen(argv[1])]`, to do a buffer overflow, you would have to give it a string that is too long, right? I still am just confused as to why you're putting a memory address into the input string, or what you think that will do.

Comment: @RandomDavis In the book I'm reading it describes a format string exploit to be something unique to variadic functions. Since the function call to printf is without a complemented variable, when inputing "%08x" from a console it retrieves the value that sits on the stack where the passed complement variables should have been (if they were passed) and by doing this one can eventually reach the address in the string. Thereafter one can use "%n" to write to the address arbitrarily. Ill find a link to the book.

Comment: @RandomDavis https://repo.zenk-security.com/Magazine%20E-book/Hacking-%20The%20Art%20of%20Exploitation%20(2nd%20ed.%202008)%20-%20Erickson.pdf page 184

Comment: On a 64-bit system, addresses are 8 bytes, not 6.

Comment: @stark I thoughts so and thats why I am slightly confused at the gdb output I get (added to the question). Any explanation for why the address is 6 bytes long?

Comment: @user349247-- What makes you think that the address is 6 bytes long? Leading zeroes are not displayed in the gdb output.

Comment: @DavidBowling ah ok that makes a lot of sense.. So if I was to write the address into memory how would I got about doing it? I ask this because if I write the leading 0 bytes into memory then wouldn't any part of the string past those bytes not be read by strcpy?

Comment: @user349247-- you could use `memcpy()`, or maybe you could use `strcpy()` with an offset, i.e., `strcpy(buffer + 2, argv[1]);`.